# What events on a power grid may cause RCCB tripping

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

For a long time I thought that one of my appliances is the cause of random RCCB trippings that happen roughly once per month.

Back when it started happening I've changed RCCBs, even switching to a different manufacturer. Didn't help, but made me sure that the problem is elsewhere.

Today I have discovered that It's not only me but my neighbors as well. Moreover it has happened at the same time for all of us. We live in different residential houses but are connected to the same 3-phase grid lines (when there is a power outage or maintenance, we are all affected).

Now I wonder what can be happening on a grid to have this effect on our RCCBs.

Comment: Where in the world are you located? I'd guess UK based on terminology, but specifying will help. As it stands, though, this is likely too broad to be answered here - there are too many possibilities. Has anyone contacted the local power company to notify them? They'd be the ones to check on a system-wide issue.